# Vertically Center Sub and Super Script in HTML

Tags: html, css, subscript, superscript

Is there a way to vertically center a sub and super script at the same time?  I would like the "e" vertically centered with the "r".

```
<span><sup>e</sup><sub>r</sub>Team 1</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change html structure?

Comment: I mean I can if that is what is needed.

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/kxo6evfh/

Comment: Ill have to wait on different answers, to much changes in your answer.

Comment: Text in sub and super script (eg "e", "r") remain unchanged? Or you can change it and add some else symbols (eg "eeee", "rrrr") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is but you pretty much have to strip away all the default stylings that are inherent to these tags. So you might as well use spans.

You'll also need a wrapper so that you can arrange them how you want...I've used flexbox but I'm sure there are other methods.

```css
body {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
span.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
sup,
sub {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: .5em;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span class="column"><sup>e</sup><sub>r</sub></span>
Team 1
</span>
```

Comment: What browsers support this?

Comment: Basically IE10 and up.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a monospace font for the [sub][super]scripts, you could do the following:

```css
span {
  font: 20px verdana;
}

sup, sub {
  font-family: monospace;       /* make letters same width so the transform aligns them properly */
}

sup + sub {
  display: inline-block;        /* transform doesn't work on inline elements */
  transform: translateX(-100%); /* move backwards */
}
```

```html
<span><sup>e</sup><sub>r</sub>Team 1</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more solution. ***Note*** this will work only when you have 1 letter in your sub or superscript.

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.5em
}
sup,
sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 0.8;
  font-size: .6em;
}
sup {
  top: 0;
}
sub {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<span><sup>e</sup><sub>r</sub>Team 1</span>
```